# React VictoryPie - How to scale slice on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, victory-charts

I'm trying to scale a slice of this Victory Pie chart on mouse hover but I'm having a difficult time getting it to render correctly. Has anyone had any luck with this? I've tried adding things like `transform: scale(1.2)` to the mutation style but it moves the slice rather than scales (I believe this is because `scale` scales based on the point of (0,0)). I've also tried playing around with `translate` or `matrix` but I can't get it to work correctly. Here's my code:

```
        <div style={{ width: '150px' }}>
          <VictoryPie
            data={[
              { x: 'Cats', y: 35, label: 'Cats \n 35%' },
              { x: 'Dogs', y: 40, label: 'Dogs \n 40%' },
              { x: 'Birds', y: 55, label: 'Birds \n 55%' }
            ]}
            labelComponent={
              <VictoryTooltip
                cornerRadius={10}
                pointerWidth={30}
                pointerLength={20}
                flyoutPadding={{ top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 25, right: 25 }}
                style={{ fontSize: '36px', fill: '#FFF' }}
                flyoutStyle={{ fill: '#414B5F' }}
                orientation="right"
              />
            }
            colorScale={['tomato', 'orange', 'gold', 'cyan', 'navy']}
            innerRadius={100}
            events={[
              {
                target: 'data',
                eventHandlers: {
                  onMouseOver: () => {
                    return [
                      {
                        target: 'data',
                        mutation: () => ({ style: { fill: 'red', width: 30 } })
                      },
                      {
                        target: 'labels',
                        mutation: () => ({ active: true })
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  onMouseOut: () => {
                    return [
                      {
                        target: 'data',
                        mutation: () => {}
                      },
                      {
                        target: 'labels',
                        mutation: () => ({ active: false })
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]}
          />
        </div>
```

I added a simple mutation that changes the slice to red on hover and that works great. I'm just having a difficult time finding the best way to make the slice scale up slightly without causing problems.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom component to render slices

```
const CustomSlice = (props) => {
  const [scale, setScale] = useState(1);

  // modified transformation from here
  // https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory/blob/844109cfe4e40b23a4dcb565e551a5a98015d0c0/packages/victory-pie/src/slice.js#L74
  const transform = `translate(${props.origin.x}, ${props.origin.y}) scale(${scale})`;

  return (
    <Slice
      {...props}
      style={{ ...props.style }}
      events={{
        onMouseOver: (e) => {
          if (props.events.onMouseOver) {
            props.events.onMouseOver(e);
          }
          setScale((c) => c * 1.2);
        },
        onMouseOut: (e) => {
          if (props.events.onMouseOut) {
            props.events.onMouseOut(e);
          }
          setScale(1);
        }
      }}
      transform={transform}
    />
  );
};
```

```
<div style={{ width: "150px" }}>
  <VictoryPie
    dataComponent={<CustomSlice />}
    data={[
      { x: "Cats", y: 35, label: "Cats \n 35%" },
      { x: "Dogs", y: 40, label: "Dogs \n 40%" },
      { x: "Birds", y: 55, label: "Birds \n 55%" }
    ]}
    labelComponent={
      <VictoryTooltip
        cornerRadius={10}
        pointerWidth={30}
        pointerLength={20}
        flyoutPadding={{ top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 25, right: 25 }}
        style={{ fontSize: "36px", fill: "#FFF" }}
        flyoutStyle={{ fill: "#414B5F" }}
        orientation="right"
      />
    }
    colorScale={["tomato", "orange", "gold", "cyan", "navy"]}
    innerRadius={100}
    events={[
      {
        target: "data",
        eventHandlers: {
          onMouseOver: (e) => {
            return [
              {
                target: "data",
                mutation: () => ({
                  style: { fill: "red", width: 30 }
                })
              },
              {
                target: "labels",
                mutation: () => ({ active: true })
              }
            ];
          },
          onMouseOut: () => {
            return [
              {
                target: "data",
                mutation: () => {}
              },
              {
                target: "labels",
                mutation: () => ({ active: false })
              }
            ];
          }
        }
      }
    ]}
  />
</div>
```

Comment: Very useful answer, thanks. Docs about Slices are non existent but its very powerful. Cheers.